# Flex Facebook App iframe z-index/transparancy problem

Tags: apache-flex, facebook, actionscript, iframe

I'm developping a Facebook Application in Flex, the application renders in facebook,
but when I click the notifications tab, it appears behind the iframe, as you can see in the image below.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lBjC.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to the problem.
In the html-template I added an attribute

`atributes.wmode = "opaque"`;